# WCF Odata error with update method

Tags: c#, wcf, odata

We are getting error when we updating the record by the wcf odata But when we are inserting the record then it's working fine. See the error message

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bad Request</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">

        <span><h1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></h1>

        <h2> <i>HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.</i> </h2></span>

        <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

        <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0

        </font>

</body>
```

And code is as follows

```
string Filter = "ServiceCallID eq " + ticketID + " and day(DateCreated) eq " + day + " and month(DateCreated) eq " + month + " and year(DateCreated) eq " + year;
                        var res = _odataGEntities.ServiceCallResults.AddQueryOption("$filter", Filter).Execute().ToList();

                        if (res != null && res.Count > 0)
                        {
                            _odataGEntities = new OdataGEntities(new Uri(ServieRefLinkGen));
                            TT.DataLayer.GenODataService.ServiceCallResult req = (from r in _odataGEntities.ServiceCallResults
                                                                                       where r.ServiceCallID == ticketID && r.DateCreated.Day == CreatedDate.Day && r.DateCreated.Month == CreatedDate.Month  && r.DateCreated.Year == CreatedDate.Year
                                                                                  select r).First();
                            req.CompletionStatus = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i]["CompletionStatus"]);
                            req.IsExactlyAsQuoted = Convert.ToBoolean(table.Rows[i]["ExactlyAsQuoted"]);
                            req.IsExtraCharges = Convert.ToBoolean(table.Rows[i]["ExtraCharges"]);
                            req.IsPartsMissing = Convert.ToBoolean(table.Rows[i]["PartMissing"]);
                            req.IsWrongParts = Convert.ToBoolean(table.Rows[i]["WrongParts"]);
                            req.IsCustomerDeniedService = Convert.ToBoolean(table.Rows[i]["CustomerDeniedService"]);
                            req.Other = Convert.ToBoolean(table.Rows[i]["OtherReason"]);
                            req.Remarks = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[i]["Remarks"]);
                            req.DateCompleted = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[i]["DateCompleted"]) != String.Empty ? Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[i]["DateCompleted"]) : (DateTime?)null;
                            req.SignerName = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[i]["SignerName"]);
                            req.CustomerEmail = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[i]["CustomerEmail"]);
                            req.ModifiedBy = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[i]["ModifiedBy"]);
                            _odataGEntities.UpdateObject(req);
                            _odataGEntities.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _odataGEntities = new OdataGEntities(new Uri(ServieRefLinkGen));
                            TT.DataLayer.GenODataService.ServiceCallResult techData = new TT.DataLayer.GenODataService.ServiceCallResult();

                            techData.ServiceCallID = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i]["TicketID"]);
                            techData.CompletionStatus = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i]["CompletionStatus"]);
                            techData.IsExactlyAsQuoted = Convert.ToBoolean(table.Rows[i]["ExactlyAsQuoted"]);
                            techData.IsExtraCharges = Convert.ToBoolean(table.Rows[i]["ExtraCharges"]);
                            techData.IsPartsMissing = Convert.ToBoolean(table.Rows[i]["PartMissing"]);
                            techData.IsWrongParts = Convert.ToBoolean(table.Rows[i]["WrongParts"]);
                            techData.IsCustomerDeniedService = Convert.ToBoolean(table.Rows[i]["CustomerDeniedService"]);
                            techData.Other = Convert.ToBoolean(table.Rows[i]["OtherReason"]);
                            techData.Remarks = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[i]["Remarks"]);
                            techData.DateCompleted = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[i]["DateCompleted"]) != String.Empty ? Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[i]["DateCompleted"]) : (DateTime?)null;
                            techData.DateCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[i]["CreatedDate"]);
                            techData.SignerName = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[i]["SignerName"]);
                            techData.CustomerEmail = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[i]["CustomerEmail"]);
                            techData.CreatedBy = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[i]["ModifiedBy"]);
                            techData.ModifiedBy = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[i]["ModifiedBy"]);
                            _odataGEntities.AddToServiceCallResults(techData);
                            _odataGEntities.SaveChanges();

                        }
                         DeleteUpdateRecordFromTable("update GenWorkResult SET IsCheckedIn=Yes WHERE TicketID = " + ticketID);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        LogFile(ex.ToString());
                    }
```

Data is inserting but when we are updating the data then we are getting error as mention above. We are unable to determine the exact problem.Please help me to find out this issue.

Comment: What does the request look like (URL and body)?

Comment: Currently I have local url of the service. For the error see HTML Body

Comment: request url is not showing. How to see in the application?                          <add key="serviereflinkgen" value="http://localhost:7105/odatadataservicegensch.svc/" />

Comment: You could use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?

Comment: I don't know about  Fiddler. Please explain this.